# Giving write permission to a user on linux server to create Anaconda env

Tags: linux, anaconda

I have both a root access and my own account on the server. Now I have anaconda installed as root and under /opt/anaconda3.

I have access to anaconda as a user on that same server. But when I try to create an environment in conda it always gives me this error.

```
NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /opt/.conda/environments.txt
  uid: 1002
  gid: 1002

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1002:1002 /opt/.conda/environments.txt
```

When I run

```
sudo chown 1002:1002 /opt/.conda/environments.txt
```

It does allow me to create an env then with no issues. But it only works for that session. Next time login again same issue.

So I think I need to add write permission to my user id to this file.

How do I do that?

Should I login as root by doing

```
sudo su -
```

And then do

```
chmod u+rw
```

But how do I specify uid and gid as mentioned above to get the write access to this file.

Thanks

Comment: Does https://medium.com/@pjptech/installing-anaconda-for-multiple-users-650b2a6666c6 help?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the below steps,

```
sudo chown 1002:1002 /opt/.conda/environments.txt

sudo chmod u+w /opt/.conda/environments.txt

sudo chmod g+w /opt/.conda/environments.txt
```

Comment: I have done the first step and it works only for that session. If u login again it again throws same error

Comment: in the last step how can I specify the exact group for write permission to this file. So so anaconda has owner as root and group as conda. I have few users added to the conda group. So if I give write permission to conda group for this particular file above then that should give write permission to everuone in that group

Comment: no what I am asking is the last step above. If I can specify the group name and write permission to that then that is great. Do u know how to specify a write permission to the whole group to a particular file? Like /opt/.coda/environment.txt?

Comment: Yeah you can give acl permissions using setfacl.
`setfacl -m user:"username":rw /path/to/file`

Comment: setfacl chnges the owner. I don't want to change owner for that file. I just want group conda to have write permission to that file

Comment: The owner will still be the same if i'm not wrong. It just gives additional permissions.
You can give additional permissions for group using,
`setfacl -m group:"groupname":rw /path/to/file`
You can check the changes using,
`getfacl /path/to/file`

Comment: got it working. I changed the owner to root and group to conda and then added write permission to group.